# Dynamically inflating textviews; setting text not working for some textviews when there are more than 2

Tags: android, dynamic, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I havent been able to find someone else with this issue so far.

What im trying to do is dynamically inflate textviews into a linearlayout and set the text of each text view.

I am able to inflate the textviews and set text for some of them, but when I inflate more than 2 textviews, i am only able to set text for 2.

in the example provided, I am trying to inflate 3 textviews and set their text.

I beleive the issue is that when im trying to set the text of the textviews, it is overwriting the text of a textview which has already had its text set.

I found this whilst debugging.

Below is the code I am using (its not pretty, i just thought I would show it like this to show all the data types etc.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < testsList.size(); i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View moduleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tests_layout, linearLayout, false);

        linearLayout.addView(moduleView, linearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

        TextView txtTestName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTestName);

        String name = testsList.get(i).getTestName();

        txtTestName.setText(name);
    }
```

I have also attached an image of the output i am getting. In the image, the textview which says "TextView" is the one which I am not able to set the text for. It should say "test5", and the Textview which currently says "test5" should actually say "test4" as far as im aware after going through the debugging

[This is an image of the result i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDZUR.png)

If anyone could shed some light on this I qould be extremely greatful!

Comment: You're assigning the inflated `View` to `moduleView`, but you're looking for the `txtTestName` `TextView` in `v`. Are you sure that's correct? That is, are you sure you shouldn't be calling `findViewById()` on `moduleView`?

Comment: Yeah that solved it!
I cant beleive I didnt pick that up... thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)

the issue was with this line of code:

```
v.findViewById(R.id.txtTestName);
```

it needed to be changed to:

```
moduleView.findViewById(R.id.txtTestName);
```